# Update large CakePHP model, but *don't* touch certain fields?

Tags: php, cakephp, models

**Using CakePHP 1.3**

I have a fairly large model in CakePHP, and I'd like to have some hidden elements on the form page to (manually) compare/validate against before saving, but when doing a `saveAll()` (with validation), I don't want these fields present (essentially to avoid them being updated).

**What's the proper way to handle this?** Remove them from `$this->data` before handing that to `saveAll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`'fieldlist'` option](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#l-1552):

```
$this->Model->saveAll($data, array('fieldlist' => array('fields', 'to', 'save')));
```

---

```
$fields = array_keys($this->Model->_schema);
$fieldsNotToSave = array('field1', 'field2');
$fieldsToSave = array_diff($fields, $fieldsNotToSave);
```

Comment: That's something I was looking into, but - since my model is a bit large, is there a complimenting function that does it the other way around: defines fields NOT to save? I have far fewer to NOT save than to save.

Comment: @anon No, you should always go for *whitelisting* instead of *blacklisting*, or it can bite you in the rear later. See my edit though for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I'll usually use `unset()` prior to the `saveAll()`.  If you think about it, it's the smarest/easiest way.  That is, unless you want to manually name the hidden input fields different than the default `data[Model][field]` that is generated by the form helper.

But then you'd have to access them manually and validate them manually.

`unset()` is fast and clear.

Comment: Stephen, this looks great, and is definitely simple. Thanks for taking the time to answer!